# Using Qt Creator and OpenCV to make a simple program

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, makefile, qt-creator

Here is the .pro file in the Qt project:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = abc123
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS        += -L/usr/local/lib

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

When I try to compile this code, Qt gives me 19 different errors (no matter what I write in classes themselves):

```
/Users/user0/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:44: error: variable has incomplete type 'class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QSizePolicy
                       ^
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:44: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QSizePolicy
                                  ^
                                  ;
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QSizePolicy::ControlTypes)
                              ^
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:158: error: expected a class or namespace
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:162: error: variable has incomplete type 'Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &, const QSizePolicy &);
                 ^
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:162: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &, const QSizePolicy &);
                            ^
                            ;
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:163: error: redefinition of 'QDataStream'
Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &, QSizePolicy &);
                 ^
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:163: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &, QSizePolicy &);
                            ^
                            ;
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:167: error: variable has incomplete type 'Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg, const QSizePolicy &);
                 ^
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:167: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg, const QSizePolicy &);
                       ^
                       ;
/Users/user05/Qt5.4.0/5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qsizepolicy.h:170: error: expected a class or namespace
inline void QSizePolicy::transpose() {
            ^
/usr/local/include/QtGui/qcursor.h:171: error: must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'QDataStream' in this scope
Q_GUI_EXPORT QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &outS, const QCursor &cursor);
             ^
             class
/usr/local/include/QtGui/qcursor.h:171: error: must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'QDataStream' in this scope
Q_GUI_EXPORT QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &outS, const QCursor &cursor);
                                     ^
                                     class
```

I am using Qt 5.4.0 version and my operating system is OS X 10.9.4. Do you have any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Create a Non-Qt project, like Plain C++ Application.

Comment: @Md.MinhazulHaque but I want to use features of the Qt project, i.e. I want to use the GUI forms creator in it.

Comment: not related to your current errors, but using opencv's c-api is a **no-no** in 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to include code from your MainWindow class. Maybe that's the cause of your problem.
Can you compile your main.cpp alone?

Comment: I tried to include it but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I meant you forget to show us the code of your MainWindow class in your question.

Comment: Secondly, can you compile the main.cpp only?

Comment: Yes, I can compile main.cpp only. But this error occurs no matter what code I write in main.cpp and mainwindow.cpp (it happens even if I leave everything as default, but after adding INCLUDEPATH to the .pro file).

Comment: Can you compile main.cpp alone in QT?

Comment: Yes, I can compile it alone in QT.

Comment: Add this in the .pro file and recompile your project: QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9

Comment: The problem may be QtCreator's messing things up. Can you try uninstall/remove Qt completely of your machine then reinstall everything?

Comment: I think you are right. I have installed Qt in my Windows instead and the code works perfectly fine there. Thank you for your support!